# How to add a content into the correct textarea by clicking on an "Add" button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

When you open the application can you please click on the "Add Question" twice so it adds 2 table rows.

Now you will see in the application that above the horizontal line there is a textarea and a plus button, and below the horizontal line shows 2 table rows, both rows displaying its own textarea and plus button.

Now my question is that I want these 2 outcomes to happen but I do need help from somebody who is good at using Jquery/Javascript in order to solve this situation:

Situation 1. If the user clicks on the plus button ABOVE the horizontal line, then it displays a modal window which contains a search bar, Please type in search bar "AAA". You will now see a list of results. Now what I want is that if the user selects a row by clicking on the "Add" button, then I want the "QuestionContnet" within that row to be displayed in the textarea above the horizontal line. At the moment the Add button just closes the modal window but doesn't add anything into the textarea.

Situation 2: This deals with the user clicking on a plus button within one of the table rows BELOW the horizontal line. I want the same thing to happen except the "QuestionContent" added is displayed in the textarea within the same row the user has clicked the plus button, no where else.

How can both situations be solved so that it adds the QuestionContent into the correct textareas depending on which plus button is clicked? I am using an Iframe to display the content within the modal window.

UPDATE:

If you look at the application, it is now displaying "[Object] [object]" in textaea when I click "Add" button. Not the "Question".

```
Below is the code for the application:



        <head>

               <script type="text/javascript">

    var plusbutton_clicked;

 function insertQuestion(form) {


var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $plusrow = $("<td class='plusrow'></td>");
var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");


 $('.questionTextArea').each( function() {

 var $this = $(this);
var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val());

 $question.append($questionText);

});

 $('.plusimage').each( function() {

var $this = $(this);
var $plusimagerow = $("<a onclick='return plusbutton();'><img src='Images/plussign.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='imageplus'/></a>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val());

$plusrow.append($plusimagerow);

 });

$tr.append($plusrow);
$tr.append($question);
$tbody.append($tr); 

form.questionText.value = "";

$('.questionTextArea').val('');

}

function plusbutton() { 
        // Display an external page using an iframe 
        var src = "previousquestions.php"; 
        $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
        return false;
    } 


    function closewindow() {     

        $.modal.close(); 
        return false;
    } 

    $('.plusimage').live('click', function() {
        plusbutton($(this));
    });


    function plusbutton(plus_id) {
        // Set global info
        plusbutton_clicked = plus_id;
        // Display an external page using an iframe
        var src = "previousquestions.php";
        $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
        return false;
    }


    function addwindow(questionText) { 

        if(window.console) console.log();
            var txt = $(this).val(questionText);

        if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 
            $('#mainTextarea').val(txt);
            } else { 
                $(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(txt); 
                }

        $.modal.close(); 
        return false;
    } 





</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">

<div id="detailsBlock">
<table id="question">
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
<td rowspan="3">
                        <textarea class="questionTextArea" id="mainTextarea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="plus" align="center">
                <tr>
                <th>
                <a onclick="return plusbutton();">
                <img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
                </a>
                <span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>
                </th>
                </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="questionBtn" align="center">
                <tr>
                <th>
                <input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
                </th>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </div>
                <hr/>

                <div id="details">
                <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="plusrow"></th>
                    <th class="question">Question</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

                </form>

                </body>
```

The details stored in the modal window comes from a seperate script known as "previousquestions.php", Below is the code where it shows the result of the "QuestionContent" field only displayed and it's "Add" button after the user has compiled a search:

```
<?php

$output = "";

        while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionresult)) {
$output .= "
<table>
      <tr>
      <td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick='parent.addwindow();'>Add</button></td>
      </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "        </table>";

        echo $output;

        ?>
```

Thank you

Application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php)

Comment: It would be best not to ask users to visit a 3rd party website.  Instead, please simply describe here the context, code, and expected results using very simple examples and short code excerpts.

Comment: This isn't a question. You are just asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: Well you get 50 points for it so it would be worth it if somebody does do it

Comment: lol, points! i like points! There is nothing more important in life than points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best way to target chosen question to specified textarea is to parameterise your `plusbutton` function:

```
function plusbutton(plus_id) {
    // Set global info
    plusbutton_clicked = plus_id;
    // Display an external page using an iframe 
    var src = "previousquestions.php"; 
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
    return false;
}
```

Of course you have to declare global `var plusbutton_clicked;` before `insertQuestion` function so other functions could change/use this information. You have to call this function with unique parameter for each plusbutton (you generate it dynamically, so this is up to you how you want to do it)

Then you can simply use it in your `$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){});` - when user clicks 'add' button you have your plusbutton id so you can navigate with jQuery to corresponding textarea and place text there.

Comment: can you show me what your add function looks like because I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: For example, you can omit id's for plusbuttons and pass jQuery instance as parameter to `plusbutton()` and then use it to navigate through DOM to get textarea. You can see very minified version of your app [here](http://http://jsfiddle.net/Wirone/skzwm/).

As you can see I used `live()` jQuery method, I suggest you to do the same. It is like `bind()` but works forward, with element which will be dynamically created in future.

Comment: I will have a look and get back to you on the outcome :) btw the link isn't working tp your jsfiddle

Comment: Of course you will have to fit my "code" to your needs and app structure, I only showed you the way. You serve search data in iframe, but this shouldn't be a problem - you're already using `parent.addwindow()`, so you only have to read question data and pass it correctly to `.add`'s function.
And yeah, my Firefox copy urls badly, [here is correct link](http://jsfiddle.net/Wirone/skzwm/).

Comment: I still can't get it to work, I am trying very hard but still can't get it to work. I have updated url of the QandATable2.php which is [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php). The php script which shows the content in the modal window's iframe is [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php). So hoepfully you can see view source and see what I tried. It's just hard with the iframe but I need the iframe. It closes the modal window when I click on "Add" button but doesn't add a question into textarea

Comment: It can't work properly because you didn't declare `var plusbutton_clicked;` as I wrote. Besides you have copied `$(plusbutton_clicked).next('textarea.questionTextArea').val(txt);` which is not valid for your app structure (I said you will have to fit it). In your app it should be `$(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(txt);` for questions below the horizontal line. For that one above the line, add `id="mainTextarea"` to textarea and access it with `$('#mainTextarea').val(txt);`. So you need to make conditions in your `.add`'s function.

Comment: For example, add `id="mainPlusbutton"` to your plusbutton above the horizontal line and in `.add` function: `if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { $('#mainTextarea').val(txt); } else { $(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQ‌​uestion').val(txt); }`. Of course you still have to be sure you get `txt` properly from search results. Use `if(window.console) console.log()` to echo steps value, it would be helpful for people who can't manipulate and debug your code.

Comment: Sorry, wat I did before posting URL was I undo back to wat it was originally and forgot to declare the variable again as you mentioned. I wil work on it and try get it working and again get back to you if it works or not

Comment: Please make sure you can read question text properly from iframe. If not, you will have to parameterise function, for example `addwindow(questionText)`, and call it from iframe with question text as parameter, which would be used inside function and appended to corresponding textarea. It shouldn't be a problem since you dynamically build search results, so you can put question text to table cell and as function parameter too. Then inside `addwindow()` you have to delete `var txt = $(this).prev('questiontd').text();` and use `.val(questionText)` for changing textarea content.

Comment: I have updated code and question under UPDATE: but you are so close. When I click on the "Add" button, it displays "[Object] [object]" within the textarea. So all we need to do is be able to get it to display question and not "[Object] [object]". URL at bottom of question.

Comment: First of all you have to generate search results in this way: `<td class="questiontd">QUESTION</td>...<td class="addtd"><button onclick="parent.addwindow('QUESTION');" class="add" type="button">Add</button></td>`. It will pass question text to `addwindow()`. Second, delete `var txt = $(this).val(questionText);` - you can use `questionText` directly (`$('#mainTextarea').val(questionText);` and `$(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(questionText);`). // When I wrote about console.log() I meant you have to put some variables there ;)

Comment: What is suppose to go in the brackets here: onclick='parent.addwindow();' because I tried 'onclick='parent.addwindow(questionText)' but it says questionText is undefined. I have deleted txt and changed it to what you said to pass questionText directly. just don't know if I need to add something in between the brackets to be able to display "Question" in textarea

Comment: FOR EXAMPLE `<td class="questiontd">What is answer to question 3 Session AAA</td>...<td class="addtd"><button onclick="parent.addwindow('What is answer to question 3 Session AAA');" class="add" type="button">Add</button></td>`. `questionText` is a variable name inside `addwindow()`, everything you will pass as parameter will be value for it; when you call `parent.addwindow('something')` inside `addwindow()` variable `questionText` = `something` and you can use it. This is very basic... Stackoverflow point isn't "write it for me", I think you should really experiment and do it yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is this ->

```
<button id="add">
```

You cannot reuse an ID over and over, or, the page will iterate to the last element with that ID and NEVER run anything on any previous elements.

Quick fix:

```
<button class="add">
```

Simple enough.

We need to get the question text, from the first column, there are so many methods to do this with jQuery selectors it's mind blowing.

**Situation 1**

Let's take a peek at *one* option ->

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  //now that we've declared the click function, let's jump up to our parent element, and grab the text in the first cell.
  var theQuestion = $("td:first-child", $(this).parent()).text();
  //Now that we've figured out how to traverse the DOM to get the data we want, we need to move that data elsewhere. 
  $('.questionTextArea').val(firstCell);
});
```

Simple enough, right? That should solve the first problem you had.
*Note: Textareas use `value` to set the data, whereas other elements will use .text()*

**Situation 2**

Alright, now we need to figure out how to add a unique identifier to the "+" row when we click, and check for that "unique identifier" when appending the data, let's do it.

You have a `<td>` with a class of plusrow, sounds good, let's make a click function out of it, and give it a cool new `class` to reference.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.plusrow', function(){
   //adding a unique class for the purpose of the click.
   $(this).addClass('activePlusRow');
 });
```

So now the "+" we clicked has a new class -- `activePlusRow`, let's go back to our initial click handler for the add button, and give it some new conditional statements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  //lets get our Question Text...
  var theQuestion = $("td:first-child", $(this).parent()).text();

  //the row is present, let's then make sure that the proper cell gets your data.
  if($('.activePlusRow').length > 0){

    $('.activePlusRow').next('.textAreaQuestion').val(theQuestion);
    $('.activePlusRow').removeClass('activePlusRow');
  }
});
```

Alright, as you can see of the above, we test to see if the activePlusRow class exists, if it does, then we iterate to the next `textarea with a class of textAreaQuestion` and change the value of it, to `theQuestion from the .add button we clicked.`

Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Hi, Frst of all thank you for taking your time to help me with this situation. Unluckily the solution you have givien me hasn't quite work. When I click on the "Add" button it does not close the modal window and add a question into the textarea at all. What am I doing wrong? I have updated the code in my question and updated the application url.

Comment: @Jahnold  I have tried your code but it is still not doing anything after add button is clicked on. It is not closing the modal window when I click on the add button and it is not adding the question into the text area. I updated code and url in question

Comment: I have put the above code in the QandA2Table.php, is this the right page or is it suppose to go in the previousquestions.php page?

Comment: @user1294925 you're missing the statement to close the modal window. I don't know what modal API you're using, so I can't tell you how to close the window.

Comment: @user1294925 I just noticed that you're using an iFrame to serve up the content in that window, that's going to be tough to surpass.

Comment: I am using simpalmodal which is developed by eric martin. Please if you have any ideas then please help with this because I am really struggling. I have set up a bounty a couple of days ago so I am willing to give 50 points if you know how to solve this problem

Comment: I have given the .add button an onclick='parent.addwindow();' method. Anyway, what is .val(firstCell) should be anyway because it is undefined.

Comment: @user1294925 Yeah. firstCell is always going to return undefined. Because you're working in an iframe, you need to use `$('body, $('iframeID').contents($('.add'))).click(function()});` to create the click for the add button, and because you need to access the data in the parent window, you also need to send the data back from the iframe using the `parent` method. These are things you need to look into, and adapt my code from there. Try this, then perhaps make a new question concerning iFrames and sending data to and back from them. That seems to be where your issues lay now, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking next() isn't the right function, since it only searches for the immediately following sibling... Try this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){  

    console.log("clicked");

   //lets get our Question Text... 
  var theQuestion = $("td:first-child", $(this).parent()).text(); 

  //the row is present, let's then make sure that the proper cell gets oru data. 
  if($('.activePlusRow').length > 0){ 

    $('.activePlusRow').next('.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(theQuestion); 
    $('.activePlusRow').removeClass('activePlusRow'); 
  }

   $.modal.close(); 
   return true;

});
```

Comment: I have tried your code but nothing happend. I hope you know I am using an iframe so the problem could be transferring the data from the modal window (previousquestions.php) to a textarea (QandATable2.php)